# MVC many to many delete

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have many to many relationship some tables. I am using entity framework.

Reservations >> ApartsToReservations << Aparts

ApartsToReservations include ReservationID and ApartID.

and my delete action below:

```
public ActionResult DeleteReservation(string resultId)
    {
        var result = Convert.ToInt32(resultId.Trim());           
        //just I have reservationID           

        return View();
    }
```

How can delete reservation?

Answer (score 1):

> How can delete reservation?

For example:

```
[HttpPost] // <- should be a POST action because it's modifying data
public ActionResult DeleteReservation(string resultId)
{
    var result = Convert.ToInt32(resultId.Trim());
    //just I have reservationID

    using (var context = new MyContext())
    {
        var reservation = new Reservation { ReservationID = result };
        context.Reservations.Attach(reservation);
        context.Reservations.Remove(reservation);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    // ... redirect to Index or something, for example:
    // return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

If you already have a `context` instance as a member of your controller class use this instead of creating a new one in the `using` block.

The code will also delete the related records in the `ApartsToReservations` link table because by default the relationships to this table are configured with cascading delete.

I'm not quite sure if this is what you are looking for because it actually doesn't matter if `Reservation` is involved in the many-to-many relationship you mentioned. It is just the (or one) standard way to delete an entity with `DbContext`.

If you are looking for something different please try to clarify your question or ask a new one which is clearer.